# 13.04 Logitech bluetooth speaker adapter pairing but no mixer output

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, logitech, adapter

I had to change

```
[General]
Enable = Socket
```

in /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf to get it to pair. But now that they are I don't get an output in pavucontrol.

```
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Registering /MediaEndpoint/HFPAG on adapter /org/bluez/3855/hci0.
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Registering /MediaEndpoint/HFPHS on adapter /org/bluez/3855/hci0.
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Registering /MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource on adapter /org/bluez/3855/hci0.
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Registering /MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink on adapter /org/bluez/3855/hci0.
E: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: org.bluez.Media.RegisterEndpoint() failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists
E: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: org.bluez.Media.RegisterEndpoint() failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists
E: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: org.bluez.Media.RegisterEndpoint() failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists
E: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: org.bluez.Media.RegisterEndpoint() failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: dbus: property 'State' changed to value 'disconnected'
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: dbus: property 'State' changed to value 'disconnected'
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: dbus: property 'State' changed to value 'disconnected'
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: dbus: property 'State' changed to value 'disconnected'
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: dbus: property 'State' changed to value 'connected'
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: dbus: property 'State' changed to value 'connected'
D: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Unknown Bluetooth minor device class 0
D: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Not restoring profile for card bluez_card.C8_84_47_15_B7_34, because already set.
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Restoring port latency offsets for card bluez_card.C8_84_47_15_B7_34.
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: Created 2 "bluez_card.C8_84_47_15_B7_34"
W: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: Profile has no transport
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: Changed profile of card 2 "bluez_card.C8_84_47_15_B7_34" to off
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-bluetooth-device" (index: #22; argument: "address=C8:84:47:15:B7:34 profile=a2dp").
I: [alsa-source] alsa-source.c: Scheduling delay of 10,06ms, you might want to investigate this to improve latency...
I: [alsa-source] ratelimit.c: 5 events suppressed
I: [alsa-source] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
I: [alsa-source] alsa-source.c: Increasing minimal latency to 2,00 ms
D: [alsa-source] alsa-source.c: latency set to 20,00ms
D: [alsa-source] alsa-source.c: hwbuf_unused=62008
D: [alsa-source] alsa-source.c: setting avail_min=442
```

What can I do to get it working?

Regards,

EDIT:

```
>>> 2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        [...cut...]
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        [...cut...]
```

EDIT2:

In pavucontrol I have "(34)Logitech Adapter". If I change the profile from "Off" to "HighFidelity Playback (A2DP)" then I get this message from pulseaudio:

```
W: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: Profile has no transport
```

EDIT3:

Funny. Disconnecting the device via blueman crashes pulseaudio:

```
E: [pulseaudio] hook-list.c: Assertion 'hook->n_firing == 0' failed at pulsecore/hook-list.c:51, function pa_hook_done(). Aborting.
```

EDIT4:

Upgrade to 13.10 didn't fix the problem either. There seems to be some incompatibility with bluez and pulseaudio and certain hardware...

EDIT5:

```
flo@io2:~$ bt-autoconnect -v

(bt-autoconnect.py:11935): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3274:48: Expected ',' in color definition
bt-autoconnect 1.0.1 scanning: C8:84:47:15:B7:34
17193981.46: (<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>, IndexError('list index out of range',), <traceback object at 0x26a3170>)
Unable to run PulseAudio CLI
17193981.46: Found BT-device: /org/bluez/10082/hci0/dev_C8_84_47_15_B7_34
17193981.46: Connecting to DBus: /org/bluez/10082/hci0/dev_C8_84_47_15_B7_34
17193993.18: (<class 'dbus.exceptions.DBusException'>, DBusException('Connect Failed',), <traceback object at 0x26a3200>)
17193994.18: (<class 'dbus.exceptions.DBusException'>, DBusException('Connect Failed',), <traceback object at 0x26a3170>)
17193995.18: (<class 'dbus.exceptions.DBusException'>, DBusException('Connect Failed',), <traceback object at 0x26a3248>)
17193996.18: (<class 'dbus.exceptions.DBusException'>, DBusException('Connect Failed',), <traceback object at 0x26a31b8>)
17193996.2: ['C8:84:47:15:B7:34', '5', 'N', 'N', 'N']
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Only two outputs. One pci card and hdmi. Added shortend version to the question.

Comment: nope. Tried a couple of times but that's not it.

Comment: OK. This is new or I just haven't seen it. In pavucontrol unter "Configuration" I got My "(34)Logitech Adapter" which was off. Changing profile to A2DP results in: `W: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: Profile has no transport`

Comment: Uh - this smells of [bug #1181106](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1181106) --> try if removing the `Enable=Socket` in audio.conf makes a change for good.

Comment: Thanks. But if I remove this I cannot connect: "Connection failed: Stream setup failed." (blueman) I try upgrading to 13.10.

Comment: What did you use instead? (I don't care which tool I use if it works)

Comment: here its just Bluez and the GNOME Bluetooth tools that come by default in Ubuntu/Unity.

Comment: [Comment #7 to bug #1199059](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1199059/comments/7) may be needed as a workaround.

Comment: Hey Takkat. You're really into this. Thank you. But this doesn't work either. It's a shame but unless I find some way to debug this I'm going to give up.

Comment: bt-autoconnect seems not to like my dbus. -> EDIT5

Comment: yeah - it throws an exception because it cant connect. You seem to have more than 1 BT device. Try to give it the MAC of your Logitech (`C8:84:47:15:B7:34`) instead of `Auto`.

Comment: Same thing. Now I see the connection led changing color.

Comment: Your Pulseaudio seems to have crashed now... tsk tsk tsk. Restart with `pulseaudio -k` may bring it back but indeed BT refuses to connect. Sometimes I have to remove the device and pair it again to get it running. Its a pain, I know.

Comment: Oh well. This is not the first time. But at least it keeps restarting automatically. It's a pitty this would have allowed me to watch movies with the audio coming from the front ... I think I have to buy some copper now.

Comment: Copper for movies! Bluetooth audio has a disturbing delay.

Answer (score 1):

Long time I was looking solution and finally helped me that link:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246613

> ### Ubuntu 14.04 Audio sink problem to Logitech Wireless Adapter
>
> Hello, jcmoriaud.
>       I had this problem recently as I bought a bluetooth speaker and attempted to connect to it with my laptop. It kept giving me "Connection Failed: Stream setup failed". I eventually figured out how to make it work like this.
>       You need to have pulseaudio installed, which you can check for in Synaptic Package Manager by typing pulseaudio into the search bar. You can install it from there if it isn't already installed.
>       Next, you need to install pavucontrol, either in Synaptic Package Manager, or by running this in the terminal.
>       Code:
>       sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
>       This is the unfortunate part. Every time you boot, you need to run this command in the terminal before any bluetooth devices attempt to connect.
>       Code:
>       pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
>       You can now go into the bluetooth manager and tell it to connect to the device as an A2DP audio sink.
>       Now, finally, if you go into the PulseAudio Volume Control, on the Playback tab, you can choose the option to send audio through the bluetooth device.
>       Good luck with this."

I using this with Blueman (GTK+ Bluetooth Manager)

Comment: `pulseaudio` is installed by default, `pavucontrol` is unrelated, and loading `module-bluetooth-discover` has already been suggested in another answer. And please stop shouting! People can read your text even when it's not bold.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having similar problems. I managed to get it working by removing Socket from the enable line in /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf referenced at the beginning of the question. Next, from the command line run:

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then you should be able to connect properly to the bluetooth audio device.

Answer (score 0):

After I cleaned the keyboard, there was no longer audio through my stereo-system, connected with a clone of the Logitech Audio Bluetooth dongle to my Ubuntu laptop.

After many wasted hours of research, I came to this simple solution:

1. Make sure there is a connection. When you play the music, you can see the MB transfer go up (=datatranfer).
2. in a terminal window, run pavucontrol
3. in pavucontrol go to the tab 'audio output' (I'm using the Dutch version, so I'm not sure wat it is called in English).
4. Look for your bluetooth dongle. Mine was called 'Esinkin BT Adapter'.
5. In my case, 'Esinkin BT Adapter' was muted. After de-clicking the mute-button, the music came through the speakers, load and clear. Yes!

[image]